# No me salen 2 decimales en el jTextField para pasarlo a una DB!

Tags: java, sqlite, jtable, jtextfield

me estoy volviendo loco y no se que hacer, a ver si alguien me puede ayudar.

Me gustaría que en el **jTextField9** me saliesen solo 2 decimales (**123.45**), porque así como esta me salen muchos decimales (123.45322222). porque luego quiero que el resultado ya con los 2 decimales se añadan a la base de datos con la secuencia de SQL, lo máximo que he podido hacer es así (123,45) pero no quiero la coma y porque me da error en la base de datos.

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    BorrarJuny();
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:MyDataB.db");
        java.sql.Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String diaJuny = jTextField7.getText();
        double val2 = Double.parseDouble(jTextField8.getText());
        double val4 = Double.parseDouble(jTextField4.getText());
        double Multi = val2 * val4;
        String valorTotal = Double.toString(Multi);
        jTextField9.setText(valorTotal);
        String val3 = jTextField9.getText();
        String sql = "Insert into Juny values('" + (diaJuny) + "','" + (val2) + "','" + (val3) + "')";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
    }
    MostrarJuny();
    SumaJuny();
}
```

[ACTUALIZACIÓN - SOLUCIÓN]
Asi me queda como me funciona, Gracias a Alberto y Christian!

```
private java.text.DecimalFormat formato = new java.text.DecimalFormat("0.00");

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    BorrarJuny();
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:Manguan.db");
        java.sql.Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String diaJuny = jTextField7.getText();
        double val2 = Double.parseDouble(jTextField8.getText());
        double val4 = Double.parseDouble(jTextField4.getText());
        String val3 = formato.format(val2 * val4).replace(",", ".");
        String sql = "Insert into Juny values('" + (diaJuny) + "','" + (val2) + "','" + (val3) + "')";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
    }
    MostrarJuny();
    SumaJuny();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo usaría un formateador.

```
private java.text.DecimalFormat formato =
                              new java.text.DecimalFormat("0.00");
```

Luego usaría ese formateador dentro del código:

```
double val2 = Double.parseDouble(jTextField8.getText());
double val4 = Double.parseDouble(jTextField4.getText());
String val3 = formato.format(val2 * val4);
```

Ahora que mejor usaría el JFormattedTextField en lugar del JTextField porque en el JFTF puedo ponerle el formato que requiero y de hecho me retornaría un número en lugar de un String.

```
Si tus textFields fueran JFormattedTextFields entonces pudieras usarlos así:

double val2 = (double)jTextField8.getValue();
double val4 = (double)jTextField4.getValue();
String val3 = formato.format(val2 * val4);
```

Te paso ligas, por si quieres aprender de estas clases. Dentro de ellas también vienen ligas a tutoriales.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html

Comment: Hola Alberto, en efecto, este me funciona, el caso es que me salen coma en vez de punto, lo he solucionado asi: **String val3 = formato.format(val2 * val4).replace(",", ".");** Muchas Gracias Alberto por tu ayuda!!!

Comment: se me hace raro que te aparezcan esas comas. Supongo que tiene que ver con tu Locale. En fin, si quieres corregirlo sugiero leas el java.text.NumberFormat y el java.text.DecimalFormat, porque son muy configurables, y se usan mucho. Saludos

Comment: Puede ser, ya que tengo como idioma "Español Internacional" y en símbolo de decimales esta la coma, podría ser por eso, lo de Number y Decimal ya probé con ellos pero me daban errores.

Answer (score 0):

de primeras la solución parece fácil, supongo que seguramente lo sea, siempre lo más simple es en lo que menos se cae...

Tú tienes en tu código esto:

```
    String valorTotal = Double.toString(Multi);
    jTextField9.setText(valorTotal);
```

Por qué no haces:

```
    String valorTotal = Double.toString(Multi);
    valorTotal = valorTotal.replace(",",".");
    jTextField9.setText(valorTotal);
```

y ya después se lo pasas al

`jTextField9`

??

Comment: Hola Enrique, la verdad es que no lo entiendo, estoy aprendiendo y no entiendo lo que quieres decir, te refieres a que cambie **String valorTotal = Double.toString(Multi);** por este **valorTotal = valorTotal.replace(",",".");**? Y que hago con **Multi**?

Comment: No, simplemente en la linea siguiente a eso hacer el `replace` que he puesto en la respuesta, el código tuyo tal cual pero añadiendo la línea que te he pasado después de `String valorTotal = Double.toString(Multi);`. De todas formas ahora modifico la respuesta para que se vea bien.

Comment: Vale, ya te he entendido, perdóname pero no es lo que busco, entiendo la forma fácil de reemplazar, y gracias a ti hoy he aprendido algo mas sobre **rerplace** no tenia conocimiento de ese procedimiento, el caso es que ya no me acuerdo como hice lo de que me saliese con la **coma** en vez de **punto**, estoy probando con **DecimalFormat** y **NumberFormat** pero me da un error de no se que de convertir objeto a numero o algo así, de todas formas muchas gracias Enrique por tu ayuda!

Comment: Vale, pues seguramente no te deja utilizar esas funcionalidades porque haces **Double.toString(Multi)**, ahi conviertes el número a cadena, ya los procesos pensados para números no se le pueden aplicar. Antes de realizar el `Double.toString` prueba a hacer el DecimalFormat, aunque ahí ya no sé muy bien como va

Comment: Ves Enrique... al final lo del **replace** lo he utilizado con otro código de Alberto y me ha funcionado, muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Primero seteas el valor o lo pasas a una variable lo mismo da:

```
String numDob = String.valueOf(Multi);
```

Luego solo cortaras el numero de la siguiente manera :

```
String numRecortado = "";
int x=0;
for(int i = 0; i < numDob.length(); i++){
   numRecortado = numRecortado + numDob.charAt(x);
   if(numDob.charAt(i).toString().equals(".")){
      i = numDob.length() - 2;
   }
   x++;
}
```

Ya que obtienes la nueva cadena entonces puedes setearla en tu `jtextfield`

```
jTextField9.setText(numRecortado);
```

Comment: Si `charAt(x)` te emite un error de conversion de `char` a `String` solo agregale al final el `.toString()` quedando de la siguiente manera : `numDob.charAt(x).toString()`

Comment: Hola Christian, me sale esto **char cannot be dereferenced** por esto **if (numDob.charAt(i).equals(".")) {** y no puedo ejecutarlo.

Comment: Hola @Mekagenden, intentaste cambiando `numDob.charAt(i).equals(".")` por `numDob.charAt(i).toString().equals(".")`?

Comment: @Mekagenden tu error (o bueno mejor dicho, MI error) es que `char` es un tipo de dato primitivo, puede ser comparado de muchas formas. Te dejo 2 links donde especifican como compararlo :

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527114/char-cannot-be-dereferenced-error `Comparacion isNNN` y https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510136/how-to-check-if-a-char-is-equal-to-an-empty-space `formas de compararlo` ; El codigo lo acabo de editar, ya deberia de funcionarte correctamente. Suerte!.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu ayuda Christian!!!